# How to separate strings in an istream only by '\n'?

Tags: c++, string, stream, iostream, separator

Given a file that contains a string "Hello World" (Note that there is a space between 'Hello' and 'World').

```
int main()
{
    ofstream fout("test.txt");
    fout.write("Hello World", 12);
    fout.close();

    ifstream fin("test.txt");
    vector<string> coll((istream_iterator<string>(fin)),
                        (istream_iterator<string>()));
    // coll contains two strings 'Hello' and 'World' rather than 
    // one string "Hello World" that is just I want.
}
```

In other words, I want that strings in an istream should only be separated by '\n' rather than ' ', '\n', etc.

How should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::getline(std::cin,str)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead. The third parameter does what you want, and it defaults to `'\n'`. Alternatively you can disable skipping whitespace by setting passing `std::cin >> std::noskipws >> str` or turn off the flag completely by doing `std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::skipws)`

Comment: I revised the original post. Please review.

Answer (score 2):

To read a line from `ifstream`, you could use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Default delimiter of [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is `\n`

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ifstream fin("test.txt");
    std::string str;

    while (std::getline(fin, str))
    {
        cout << str << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I revised the original post. Please review.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str;
while(fscanf(fin,"%s\n",&str));
```